# Integral of Complex Gaussian: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2\pi x +i\omega)^2}dx$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, complex-integration

I wonder if the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{{\infty}}e^{-\alpha x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$, for $\alpha\neq 0$, how could the integral
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2\pi  x +i\omega)^2}dx$ be simplified as follows: $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2\pi  x +i\omega)^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2\pi  x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}.$$ 
I understand how to pass from the second equality to last one via scaling $x\rightarrow \frac{x}{2\pi}$, however to get the immediate second part from the first needs some complex integration identity. What sort of identity allows us to do that? I count on your answer.

Comment: Consider the integral going (along a rectangle) from $-R$ to $R$ along the real axis. Then up to $R+iw$ then down to $-R + iw$ and finally down to $-R$. The total integral is zero by the residue theorem. Show that as $R\to\infty$ the integral along the sides goes to $0$ and you get the desired result.

Comment: I think the easiest way to justify it is thisone : $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2\pi  x +i\omega)^2}dx-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2\pi  x)^2}dx=0$ is true for $\omega$ purely imaginary, and since the LHS is complex analytic in $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$, the equality is true for every $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$   @Winther

Comment: I think your commmets are helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @reuns, I had edited my question by adding that $\omega\in \mathbb{R}$, perhaps positive. It is $i\omega$ that is purely imaginary not $\omega$ itself.

Comment: I'm saying it is obvious for $ \omega \in i\mathbb{R}$ and properties of analytic functions implies it is true for  $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ thus for $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Winther,  I guess you mean the integral of the difference $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\big(\int_{-R+i\omega}^{R+i\omega}e^{-(2\pi x+i\omega)^2}dx -\int_{-R+i\omega}^{R+i\omega}e^{-(2\pi x)^2}dx\big)$ by the total integral to vanish (Sorry this could be bad expression) . Right?

Comment: Yes. When you integrate over the rectangle contour then one integral will be in the + direction and the other in the - direction (which depends on if you decide to integrate  clockwise or counter clockwise) so you end up with something like what you have written above (should be $\int_{-R}^Re^{-(2\pi x)^2}dx - \int_{-R}^Re^{-(2\pi x+i\omega)^2}dx = 0$ as $R\to\infty$)

Comment: Thanks. I think now is more less clear.

Comment: Ah okay great @reuns.

Comment: @Winther To introduce those things to people having background only in real analysis but not in complex analysis I think you should start by introducing $F(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)k!}$ such that $F'(z) = e^{-z^2}$, then OP's problem becomes $\lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x+i\omega)-F(x) = 0$

Comment: @reuns The question is tagged "complex integration".

Answer (score 0):

$$
\eqalign{
  & I(n) = \int_{x =  - n}^{\;n} {e^{\, - \left( {2\pi x + iw} \right)^{\,2} } dx}  = e^{\,w^{\,2} } \int_{x =  - n}^{\;n} {e^{\, - 4\pi ^2 x^2 } e^{\, - 4iw\pi x} dx}  =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\,w^{\,2} } \left( {\int_{x =  - n}^{\;n} {e^{\, - 4\pi ^2 x^2 } \cos \left( {\,4w\pi x} \right)dx} 
 - i\int_{x =  - n}^{\;n} {e^{\, - 4\pi ^2 x^2 } \sin \left( {\,4w\pi x} \right)dx} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\,w^{\,2} } 2\int_{x = 0}^{\;n} {e^{\, - 4\pi ^2 x^2 } \cos \left( {\,4w\pi x} \right)dx}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{2e^{\,w^{\,2} } } \over {4w\pi }}\int_{x = 0}^{\;n} {e^{\, - \left( {{{2\pi } \over {4w\pi }}} \right)^2 \left( {4w\pi x} \right)^2 }
 \cos \left( {4w\pi x} \right)d\left( {4w\pi x} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{2e^{\,w^{\,2} } } \over {4w\pi }}\int_{y = 0}^{\;4w\pi n} {e^{\, - \left( {{1 \over {2w}}} \right)^2 y^2 } \cos y\,dy}  \cr} 
$$
and
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \,\infty } I(n) = {{2e^{\,w^{\,2} } } \over {4w\pi }}{{\sqrt \pi  e^{\, - w^{\,2} } } \over {2{1 \over {2w}}}} = {1 \over {2\sqrt \pi  }}
$$

Comment: What transformation is this $2\pi x\rightarrow 2\pi y$, did you take $y=x+i\frac{\omega}{2\pi}$? In that case, I guess you take $y$ complex which may not be the case.

Comment: I mean the transformation $2\pi x+i\omega \rightarrow 2\pi y$.

Comment: You are presenting this as it's trivial, though the things you suggest are not valid things to do. There is no such thing as one "$\infty$". You are making a substitution involving complex numbers. A proper treatment of this would involve considering a closed integral in the complex plane + the residue theorem.

Comment: @MD: it is clearer now?

Comment: @Winther: the Fourier Transform is not an integral over a closed path !

Comment: You clearly didn't understand my comment. Nowhere did I say that

Comment: @Winther: good, so the misunderstanding is cleared. Now pls. be aware that in the "engineering" use of it (as my previous hint) $\infty + iw$ is "taken" just as $\infty$ as demonstrated in new version above, and as done in the steps reported in the post.

Comment: Hi guys, this is a great job. You paved my way to understand how to tackle the problem. Before, I was stuck on how to tackle it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @M.D.: thanks for the appreciation: I would like you might consider to upvote, so that to balance (at least) the downvote of Winther

Comment: @GCab, I upvoted already. I do not know who downvoted the answer again.